# MAC Address on Virtuozzo VPS

Tags: vps

How do I apply a MAC Address (of my choice, not random) to a VE (Virtuozzo powered)

I tried this:

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --mac "actual mac address here" --save
Invalid usage. Option --ifname not specified

In order to license software for use for my client's company, the vendor needs the MAC Addresses setup for their vps' virtual enet interfaces.

Tried various methods, not working.

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --mac --venet "mac-address" --save
Bad parameter for --mac: --venet

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --mac --eth0 "mac-address" --save
Bad parameter for --mac: --eth0

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --venet --mac "mac-address" --save
VEID#: unrecognized option `--venet'

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --mac "mac-address" --save
Invalid usage. Option --ifname not specified

[root@node root]# vzctl set VEID# --mac "mac-address" --venet --save
VEID#: unrecognized option `--venet'

Edit/Delete Message

The Virtuozzo NODE uses Centos, as does the VPS container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the --netif parameter to assign the mac address to the container virtual network adapter

Comment: This is not working either.

http://tinypaste.com/ddc10

Comment: Yeah, netif needs a value for the network adapter, like eth0 or vznet , thats why the error says netif is ambigous.

Answer (score 2):

Since you paid for Virtuozzo, I'd suggest asking Parallels for support directly. If you were using the free/open source version, OpenVZ, I'd tell you to use a [virtual ethernet device](http://wiki.openvz.org/Virtual_Ethernet_device#MAC_addresses), because the default networking method used does not allow MAC addresses.

Comment: Paid support expired, renewal is a rip-off.

Comment: virtual ethernet device ftw.